# Editing symbol attributes with R::grid

Tags: r, r-grid

For `grid` practice purposes, I am trying to adjust the plot symbol. The idea is to connect min/max values with a vertical line, and give both symbols & line the same color fill without visible outline.

I've figured out most steps. My problem is with removing the symbol outline and changing the symbol.

```
library(grid)
n    <- 10
mins <- 10*runif(n)
maxs <- mins + 5*runif(n)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1)))
vp <- dataViewport( xData = 1:n , yData = c(mins,maxs) , name = "theRegion")
pushViewport(vp)
grid.rect()
grid.points(1:n,mins , gp = gpar(pch=2,col="blue",fill="blue"))
grid.edit("dataSymbols",pch=2)
# --------------------------------
# Error in editDLfromGPath(gPath, specs, strict, grep, global, redraw) : 
#  'gPath' (dataSymbols) not found
# --------------------------------
grid.points(1:n,maxs,  gp = gpar(pch=2,col="yellow"))
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()

for(i in 1:n){
  grid.lines(x = unit(c(i,i),"native"),
             y = unit(c(mins[i],maxs[i]),"native"), 
             gp = gpar(col = "green",lwd=6))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of issues:
1. `pch` is not a `gpar` parameter - move `pch` outside `gpar`.
2. pch=2 has a 'col' but does not have a 'fill'. A triangle-shaped symbol with both fill and col is pch=24.
3. If you want to edit a named grob, you need a grob with that name.

```
library(grid)
n    <- 10
mins <- 10*runif(n)
maxs <- mins + 5*runif(n)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1)))
vp <- dataViewport(xData = 1:n, yData = c(mins,maxs), name = "theRegion")
pushViewport(vp)
grid.rect()

# Symbols are triangles with blue border and yellow fill.
# Note the grob's name
grid.points(1:n, mins, pch = 24, gp = gpar(col = "blue", fill = "yellow"), name = "dataSymbols")

# Edit that grob so that the symbols do not have a border
grid.edit("dataSymbols", gp = gpar(col = NA))

# Edit that grob so that the symbol changes to pch = 2
grid.edit("dataSymbols", pch = 2)
# OOPS! The symbols have only a fill assigned, but pch = 2 does not have a fill 

# So, give the symbols a blue border
grid.edit("dataSymbols", gp = gpar(col = "blue"))
```